# openapi generator Select Server Configuration

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi 3.0 and openapi generator 5.4.0 to generate code for go. I have multiple servers configured. There is a "Select Server Configuration" part in README. It supplies example, but I'm unable to find out how and where to use it.

> For using other server than the one defined on index 0 set context value sw.ContextServerIndex of type int.

```
ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), openapi.ContextServerIndex, 1)
```

Comment: Did you find out any more information on this? Trying to locate how to set up the server myself when using `openapi-generator-cli` for typescript fetch. I imagine it's done with the configuration options you pass in to it when initializing, but not sure what the syntax/option is.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I changed order of servers in openapi yaml: now localhost is the first and it works fine

Comment: Working solution was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74850989/is-it-a-way-to-generate-endpoint-api-basepath-as-variable-with-openapi-generator . I use this in my own project after experimenting a lot with trying to choose one server via openapi-generator-cli option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can do the following when you pass in the config options.

```js
import {
  Configuration,
  ConfigurationParameters,
  UsersApi, // Will be whatever you tagged your endpoints with and `Api`
} from "your-sdk";
const configParameters: ConfigurationParameters = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: sessionToken ? `Bearer ${sessionToken}` : "",
  },
  basePath: 'http://localhost:3022/rest/v1'
};

const configuration = new Configuration(configParameters);
const userApi = new UsersApi(configuration);
userApi.aPostMethod({aPostMethodRequest: {email: "an@email.com"}})
```

For some reason I seem to need to prefix my params for a POST request with a name that matches the called method, but with `Request` after it