# Is it a way to generate endpoint api basePath as variable with OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: angular, typescript, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using OpenAPI Generator cli to generate endpoint api service from template.yml

In my template i define server url in string and i would like to pass as a variable because i have dev env & prod env with differents url.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyApiCustom'
```

Can i pass options in cli command openapi generate which it can be use in template, or use env variable in template ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.  OpenApi 3.x supports [server templating](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/#:%7E:text=Server%20Templating).  For example:

```yaml
servers:
  - url: http://{env}:{port}/{path}
    variables:
      env:
        default: prod
        description: The current environment
      port:
        enum:
          - '8080'
          - '8098'
        default: '8080'
      path:
        default: MyApiCustom
```

You can then define these variables in your cli using the following cli parameter:

`--server-variables=env=dev,port=8098,path=devApi`

This feature was added in [this commit](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/3363) from 2019.

*Note: you must have a default specified in your OAS file.*